# Quadrupling list with one-liner

Tags: python

I can do it with long, ugly way:

```
list_1 = ['AA','BB']

quadrupled = []
for i in list_1:
    quadrupled.append(i)
    quadrupled.append(i)
    quadrupled.append(i)
    quadrupled.append(i)
```

Or shorter, using `.extend()`:

```
for i in list_1:
    quadrupled.extend([i] * 4)
```

But I'm wondering if I can do it using list comprehension.

```
quadrupled = [([i] * 4) for i in list_1]
```

gives me list of lists, but I want flat list.

I know that readability of such one-liner might not be too good as it may require to use some nesting and it may be better to stick to `.extend()` but i'm just wondering if it's possible.

I've seen the same for doubling, not quadrupling.

Comment: so the result you are looking after is `['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB']`?

Comment: @ Ev. Kounis yes, sorry, should have stated it clearly.

Comment: Why don't you use `answer = [list_1[0]]*4 + [list_1[1]]*4 `

Comment: @Bazingaa i don't see it working. My list might be longer than just two elements and i have to go through every element.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case then it's not the perfect solution. You didn't mention it in your question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a list comprehension using 2 `for` loops: the first to iterate over the elements of the input list, the second to append 4 times each element. Here is a solution that I find quite readable:

```
list_1 = ['AA','BB']

quadrupled = [i for i in list_1 for _ in range(4)]

print(quadrupled)
# ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB']
```

Another way to do it with a list comprehension is to use `zip()` function, but I find it less readable:

```
quadrupled = [i for j in zip(list_1,list_1,list_1,list_1) for i in j]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answer, it's working. I have to read up on nested list comprehension though, as i can't really write any just out of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, in numpy you can use `numpy.repeat`, for example:

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat(['AA','BB'],4)
```

The return of that will be a numpy array of the quadruplication
If you'd like it as a list (although recommended to use numpy array), you can simply convert it back with the `list` function

Comment: Thanks, `quadrupled = list(np.repeat(test_list,4))` works. I'm not using pandas or numpy in this code, so i'd rather convert it to regular list.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools` `chain` + `repeat`:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

list_1 = ['AA','BB']

res = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 4) for i in list_1))

print(res)

['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `chain` and `repeat` from `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> list_1 = ['AA','BB']
>>> list(chain(*zip(*repeat(list_1, 4))))
['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB']
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply multiply with list a comprehension

```
>>> list_1 = ['AA' ,'BB']
>>> list_1 = [i for i in list_1 for _ in range(4)]
>>> list_1
['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB']
```

Comment: Sorry, if i wasn't precise. I want `['AA, 'AA, 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB']`, not mixing elements.

Comment: I think he wants the results packed next to each other: `["AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB"]`